# Regex remove only certain tags from html

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove only a set of html tags (b,i,p, end of tags) from a given html.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<[^bip/](.*?)>");
```

However, this also removes img tag coz of .*. What should I change to prevent removal of `img`

**EDIT**: I'm doing this on Android app. I know regex is the worst way, but Inbuilt spannable classes are not working as expected and I cant import a library just for html parsing. My purpose is to just detect if other tags exist OR not. Also, html is pretty small (upto 10 lines max), performance shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: you want to remove start and end tags or only end tags?

Comment: Maybe you should reconsider using regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: The purpose is to detect existence of other tags. So I dont need end tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to work into xml (or html) is a bad idea : you definitely want to use a parser.

In your case, you want to match:

```
<\s*/?\s*[bip]\s*>
```

Remove simple letter tag

(and same closing tag) and take into account some spaces are valid; you also need to run your regex as multiline.
It might work, but it's dangerous and you might have unexpected side effects

**EDIT**:
I understood you just want to remove the tags, not the actual content inside the tag

**EDIT2**:
current pattern matches the 3 tags, not their content. In a substitution regexp (replacing by nothing), it would remove these formatting tags, not the embedded content.

Comment: This just keeps these three tags, I wanted to remove them instead!

Comment: it does not keep them, it matches them : s/pattern//gmi will remove them (substitution regexp, I only gave the matching pattern)

Comment: Don't forget to check for the entity reference values as well - or double escape them if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

This has been said a million times on [`stackoverflow`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not).

**Don't process HTML, XHTML or XML with regexes. They aren't regular languages, they are context free languages and can't be correctly processed with regular expressions.**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your regex, seems very different from what you say you want. Use something like below:

```
<([bip])>.*?</\1>
```

**And if possible, don't use the above or any other regexes. There are various other better ways to do this. Search here or on google.**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove only `<b>,<p>,<i>` and `</b>,</p>,</i>` tags then you can use following regex :

```
(</?b>|</?p>|</?i>)
```

Comment: Your solutions is exactly the opposite

Answer (score 0):

Most of the sample regex only checks a tag starts with a certain tag. For instance, you may want to remove `<b>`, but not `<br>`. So, in most of the sample regex, if you add `<b>` in the tags list, it automatically removes `<br>` as well. I use `/<\/?(font|div|b)(\/|>|\s.*?>)/g`. This regex prevents starts with issue. This sample will find only `font`, `div` and `b`, not match with `br`.