# Identify html tags present using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm doing this on android and I don't wish to use any html parsers (libraries) since the sole purpose is to know what html tags are present other than  < b > < i > and  < p >

Im using:

> Pattern p =
>   Pattern.compile("<^bip/>");

This works well returning all tags other than B, I, P, BUT it also removes < img > tag. Can someone modify it to not ignore img tag?

Comment: This relly looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828285/regex-remove-only-certain-tags-from-html/5828362#5828362 <<<< couldn't you edit your original tag instead of spawning a new one ?

Comment: everyone else hijacked the thread with their opinions. No one was willing to provide accurate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your regex definition should be like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)<(?![bip]\\b).*?/?>");
```

- `?!` for negative look ahead // i.e. `<` not followed by (`b` or `i`  or `p`) + word boundary
- `(?i)` for ignore case comparison
- `.*?` for optionally grabbing 0 or more characters after opening tags
- `/?` for making trailing slash optional before `>`

Comment: Oh my bad, probably didn't get the question right first time. Edited the answer. Pls try again.

Comment: Yes sure I added some description already in my answer above, adding more here. This regex is using negative lookahead as explained here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html. My answer basically means match `<` if NOT immediately followed by (b or i or p) AND a word boundary. So `<i>` will be ignored but `<img>` will be matched or `<b>` will be ignored but `<br/>` will match.

Comment: Nice, but I have a few nits.  (1) isn't the `/?` redundant with `.*?`?   (2) Shouldn't the `.*?` match newlines, or have the DOT_ALL flag?  (3) To properly handle `<b:foo>` maybe replace the `\\b` with `(?!=[A-Z0-9:-])`.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: Completely agree with your points # 1 & 2 here. However about 3: OP wanted to negate matching standard HTML tags `<p>`, `<b>` and `<i>` on Android and AFAIK `<b:foo>` doesn't fall into that category.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find which tags are in your document, I would advise to use a more-than-one step:

- extract all tags and put them in a list; regexp is fairly simple <(.*?)>
- sort your list for unicity, filter it to remove your unwanted symbols (like i,b,p...)

Doing this that way can be encapsulated into a class, is more configurable if ever you want to filter other tags, is easier to understand and maintain on the longer term than a cryptic regex.

My 2c

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to recognize or to remove tags?

And do you want to distinguish between tags like `<img onerror='alert("PWNED")' src=bogus>` and ones that meet some definition of legit?

See http://code.google.com/p/owasp-java-html-sanitizer/source/browse/trunk/src/main/org/owasp/html/HtmlPolicyBuilder.java for a way to create lightweight HTML sanitization policies in java.

Comment: @taranfx, You said "BUT it also removes `<img>` tag".  What did you mean by that?

Comment: my Regex removes it, but I don't want to.